# Pin file to IPFS using pinata

Tags: ipfs

I'm using pinata and trying to pin some files to ipfs. These files are coming from user input and not readed from the fs. Having this code:

```
export const deployFile = async (
  file: Express.Multer.File,
  httpService: HttpService,
): Promise<string> => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', Readable.from(file.buffer));

  try {
    const observable = httpService
      .post(process.env.PINATA_BASE_URL + '/pinning/pinFileToIPFS', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`,
          pinata_api_key: process.env.PINATA_API_KEY,
          pinata_secret_api_key: process.env.PINATA_API_SECRET_KEY,
        },
      })
      .pipe(map((response) => response.data));

    const response = await lastValueFrom(observable);

    return response.IpfsHash;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error deploying image reason: ${error.response.data.error}`);
  }
```

Always hitting error `Invalid request format.`. How ever if file is readed from the fs using:

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), '/images/1.jpeg')));
```

Everything work as expected and file is successfully pinned on Pinata. So i'm thinking:
`Readable.from(file.buffer)` is different than `createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), '/images/1.jpeg'))` Any idea how to deploy user files directly to ipfs and not reading them from FS?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Pinata API, then it's a straightforward way to do it from the node.js side

```
async function storeImages(imagesDirPath) {
  const fullImagesPath = path.resolve(imagesDirPath);
  const files = fs.readdirSync(fullImagesPath);
  let responses = [];
  console.log("Uploading to Pinata !!!");
  console.log("paths ", fs.createReadStream(fullImagesPath + "/" + files[0]));
  for (fileIndex in files) {
    const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream(
      `${fullImagesPath}/${files[fileIndex]}`
    );
    try {
      const response = await pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile);
      responses.push(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  return { responses, files };
}
async function storeTokeUriMetadata(metadata) {
  try {
    const response = await pinata.pinJSONToIPFS(metadata);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/polluterofminds/218b913de7094d64df5f6cf6acd7c4a4) how to use `

```
const { Readable } = require("stream");
const FormData = require("form-data");
const axios = require("axios");

(async () => {
  try {
    const base64 = "BASE64 FILE STRING;
    const imgBuffer = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");

    const stream = Readable.from(imgBuffer);
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', stream, {
      filepath: 'FILENAME.png'
    })

    const res = await axios.post("https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS", data, {
      maxBodyLength: "Infinity",
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
          pinata_api_key: pinataApiKey,
          pinata_secret_api_key: pinataSecretApiKey
      }
    });

    console.log(res.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```